# Tooltip documentation in Visual Studio 2008 - not enough info

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, documentation, tooltip

Is it possible for the tooltip documentation in VS2008 (C#) to display not just some of the doc, but all of it?

E.g.

```
/// <summary>
/// Method description
/// </summary>
/// <param name="param1">Parameter no 1</param>
/// <param name="param2">Parameter no 2</param>
```

When I hover the mouse over method call, it displays just the "Method description" text. I'd like to see parameters or returns too. Maybe other possible documentation.

I mean, I used to code in Eclipse a while (in Java) and there was very nice tooltip documentation, where there was the whole doc "comment" written on the method, not just text between "summary" tag. Moreover, it was possible to open the doc in a separate dockable window. And the doc was nicely formatted, in XML structure (look like HTML formatting). Here in VS it seems like it doesn't format it based on used XML tags (e.g. when I use a tag to create an HTML-like list, no list appears in the tooltip, just space-separated words in one row).

Answer (score 2):

You will get the parameter information once you open the ( in calling the method.

In this case: public void Hello(string param1, string param2)

The moment you type "Hello(" the tooltip will show the documentation for param1.
Once you type "Hello(value1," you will see the documentation for param2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I know, thanks. :-)

I mean, I used to code in Eclipse a while (in Java) and there was very nice tooltip documentation, where there was the whole doc "comment" written uppon the method, not just text between "summary" tag. Moreover, it was possible to open the doc in separate dockable window. And the doc was nicely formated, according to xml structure (look like html formating). Here in VS it seem like it doesn't format it based on used xml tags (e.g. when I use  tag to create html-like list, there appears no list in tooltip, just space-separated words in one row).